# Error message in login (HTML and php)

Tags: php, html

I try to write login procedure where I can display error messages. My login form in HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="login" action="data/login.php" method="post">
    <H2>Rgister</H2>
    Your login and password:
    <br><br>
    <div id="login-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Login:</div><div id="login-fld" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="username" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
    <div id="login-name">Pass:</div><div id="login-fld"><input name="password" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="image" src="obr/login-klw.png" alt="Submit" width="103" height="42" style="margin-left:90px;">
    <br><br>

    <?php if ($_GET["log_err"]) { if ($_GET["rsn"] == "pass") { ?>
    <html><body><h3>Error no 1</h3></body></html>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <html><body><h3>Error no 2</h3></body></html>
    <?php } exit; } ?>
</form>
```

and php code for that:

```
... [ question to the database and return in $result object ] ...

        if ($result->num_rows == 0)  {
            setcookie('logged_in', false, time() + 600, '/');
            die(header("location:../index.html?log_err=true&powod=pass"));
        }
        else  {
            setcookie('logged_in', $_POST['username'], time() + 600, '/');
            header("Location: /AAA/app.html");
        }
    }
    else  {
        setcookie('logged_in', false, time() + 600, '/');
        die(header("location:../index.html?log_err=true&powod=empty"));
}
```

and both messages ("Error no 1" and "Error no 2") I see everytime I load
 this page. I don't know why and how to debug this part of code. Anybody could help me?

Problem is that this form looks like this:
[image]

I see error massages all the time.

Comment: please paste the whole code

Comment: why you used $_GET?

Comment: You put `<html><body>.....</body></html>` inside of `<form></form>`.

Comment: Your HTML code is not inside a .html file, is it? Remember it needs to be in a .php file

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? I tried your if snippet and it works as expected.

Comment: You use each of `id="login-name"` and `id="login-fld"`  twice. `Id` should be unique in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: first file name should be "index.php" not "index.html", second in place of:

```
<?php if ($_GET["log_err"]) { if ($_GET["rsn"] == "pass") { ?>
```

should be:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['log_err'])) if ($_GET["log_err"]) { if ($_GET["rsn"] == "pass") { ?>
```

On app start there was no $_GET so it's presence should be testet first.
Thank you for responses.

Comment: Stop using `$_GET`, use SESSIONs instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem you will face over and over again.  When in dev mode learn to dump your variables onto the screen to peer inside what the server is understanding.

In its simplest form all you have to do is this underneath your code.

`<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>`

Then maybe, `var_dump($_GET["log_err"]);` and so on.

Other correct answers not withstanding, and oh, check you have no var_dump() statements lingering around before you publish your code.

Good luck.